# How to Move an Object On Y Axis with Mouse in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, mousemove

I want control the transform with mouse just for Y axis as it is moving on X axis by it self.

I use **Vector2.MoveTowards** to move it on X axis.

The transform must be moved by any touch and drag on the screen. So I wrote my codes in the Update function

My Codes :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Camera playerCamera;

    public float speed = 12.0F;
    private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero,Point,last;

    void Start()
    {
        Point = transform.position;
        last = transform.position;
        if (playerCamera == null)
        {
            playerCamera = Camera.main;
        }
        playerCamera.transparencySortMode = TransparencySortMode.Orthographic;
    }

    void Update(){
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        Point = last;
        moveDirection.x = transform.position.x+speed;
        moveDirection.y = transform.position.y;

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
            last = ray.GetPoint (0);
            transform.position = new Vector2 (transform.position.x, last.y - Point.y);
        }
        else
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards( transform.position,moveDirection,speed*Time.deltaTime);

         //moveDirection.y -= 20.0f * Time.smoothDeltaTime;


        //After we move, adjust the camera to follow the player
        playerCamera.transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, playerCamera.transform.position.y , playerCamera.transform.position.z);
    }
}
```

How can I solve it?